# How to set length of major and minor ticks in Excel?

Tags: excel, charts, openxml

With matplotlib it's possible to set the tick length using [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params), e.g.:

```py
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', length=10)
```

How to do so in Excel?

- Unfortunately, the user interface does not seem to provide an option for the tick length.
- I also could not find the corresponding XML property of Office Open XML (OOXML) format.

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk
  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing.charts.majortickmark?view=openxml-2.8.1

Do I miss something? Or does Excel not support configuring tick lengths at all?

Comment: Just a tip: I would create the Excel manually and then use the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) to reflect the `C#` code for it.